# How to create HashMap from a Vector in Scala

Tags: scala, spray-json

I have this Vector:

```
val imageIds = Vector(
  "XXXX1",
  "XXXX2",
  "XXXX3"
)
```

And I currently create an Array using the following method:

```
def makeTheImageDataArray: Vector[JsObject] = {
  imageIds.map(SingleImageData(_, "theURL", "theStatus").asJsObject)
}
```

with this case class:

```
case class SingleImageData(ImageId: String, URL: String, Status: String) {
  def imageId: String = ImageId
  def getURL: String = URL
  def status: String = Status

  def asJsObject: JsObject = JsObject(
    "ImageId" -> JsString(imageId),
    "URL" -> JsString(getURL),
    "Status" -> JsString(status)
  )
}
```

Which produces:

```
Vector(
  {"ImageId":"XXXX1","URL":"theURL","Status":"theStatus"},
  {"ImageId":"XXXX2","URL":"theURL","Status":"theStatus"},
  {"ImageId":"XXXX3","URL":"theURL","Status":"theStatus"}
)
```

Instead of producing a Vector, I want to create a HashMap instead, with the ImageId as the key, i.e. :

```
Map(
  XXX1 -> {"URL":"theURL","Status":"theStatus"},
  XXX2 -> {"URL":"theURL","Status":"theStatus"},
  XXX3 -> {"URL":"theURL","Status":"theStatus"}
)
```

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `"ImageId" -> JsString(imageId)` from `asJsObject`, then

```
imageIds.map(id => id -> SingleImageData(id, "theURL", "theStatus").asJsObject).toMap
```

or if SingleImageData doesn't need to know the id, remove ImageID entirely from SingleImageData, and

```
imageIds.map(_ -> SingleImageData("theURL", "theStatus").asJsObject).toMap
```